# Search for last 30 days "a particular tag" answers for a particular user is returning all answers given by that user instead

Tags: bug, search, top-users

What I am trying to do is fetching all answers posted by me which are tagged with a particular tag. Here the example tag I have chosen is ["Dharma"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dharma) and the site is [Hinduism Stack Exchange](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/).

Visit this link: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/dharma/topusers

So, it shows that I have posted 2 answers in the last 30 days whereas I have posted 61 answers in all for that particular tag.

When I click on the ["61"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:4732%20[dharma]%20is:answer) it should return all those 61 answers and it is doing so too.

But when I click on the "2", instead of returning just the 2 answers, it is returning all the 61 answers.

Similar is the case if I switch to any other tags. For example, let's take the [Scripture tag](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/scripture/topusers).

Here too, it shows only 2 answers for me in the last 30 days, but when I click on the "2" the search returns [all the 183 answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:4732%20[scripture]%20is:answer) that I have posted so far.

So, is this a bug or that is the way it is supposed to be?

Comment: So it is not needed to be answered/addressed? the other question is also not answered although it is asked long ago.

Comment: Heh ... 3 months ago are not long enough here :)

Comment: Oh I thought here questions get answers very quickly .. @älёxölüt

Comment: Many answers here should contain a fix description from the developer team, hence many time to implement.